# Memory error en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Cuando hago por ejemplo `print(10 * (10**18))` no hay problema, pero cuando cambio el primer numero por una variable, por ejemplo `print(amount * (10 ** 18))` obtengo un *error de memoria*, aunque `amount` valga `1`.

Codigo:

Funcion 1:

```
currencies = {'bnb': 18, 'urub': 8}

def to_wei(amount:int, currency:str):
    decimals = currencies[currency.lower()]
    return amount * (10 ** decimals)
```

La funcion 1 es llamdada dentro de la funcion 2:

```
async def transfer_bnb(_from=None, to=None, key=None, amount=0):
    print(uwutils.to_wei(amount, "BNB"))
    try:
        estimated_gas = w3.eth.estimate_gas({
            'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(_from),
            'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price,
            'to': to,
            'from': _from,
            'value': uwutils.to_wei(amount, "BNB")
        })
        signed_txt = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction({
            'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(_from),
            'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price,
            'gas': estimated_gas,
            'to': to,
            'from': _from,
            'value': uwutils.to_wei(amount, "BNB")
        }, key)

        w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txt.rawTransaction)
        return {'error': False}
    except ValueError:
        return {'error': True, 'message':'Not enough funds'}
```

La funcion 2 es llamada dentro de una funcion asincrona:

```
async def routine(check_var, amount_entry, address_entry, account):
    currency = check_var.get()
    if currency == 'NONE':
        pass
    elif currency == 'BNB':
        amount = amount_entry.get()
        reciever = address_entry.get()
        if w3.toChecksumAddress(reciever):
            print(await tx.transfer_bnb(_from=account.public_key, to=reciever, key=account.private_key,
                                         amount=amount))
        else:
            showerror("Error", "Wrong address")
    elif currency == 'URUB':
        amount = amount_entry.get()
        reciever = address_entry.get()
        if w3.toChecksumAddress(reciever):
            print(await tx.transfer_urub(_from=account.public_key, to=reciever, key=account.private_key,
                                         amount=amount))
        else:
            showerror("Error", "Wrong address")
```

check_var es una variable string de tkinter, y las entradas son entradas comunes de tkinter tambien.

Por ultimo la rutina se ejecuta en un evento de button:

```
def send_button_click():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(routine(check_var=check_var, amount_entry=amount_entry, address_entry=address_entry, account=account))
```

Comment: creo que ya sabes como funciona el sitio, podrías colocar tu código?, pues no he logrado replicar tu problema

Comment: Humm ... no veo que haya un problema. Mejor publica un código completo (mínimo, completo) que exhiba el error, no pedacitos.

Comment: Código añadido.

Comment: Avisen si no es suficiente.

Comment: Donde está la variable `currencies`?

Comment: El paréntesis fue un error de copiado, currencies está afuera de la función to_wei que forma parte de un módulo llamado uwutils. Incluye to_wei y from_wei

Comment: Mmm.... el error puede deberse por el numero tan grande que guardas

Comment: Pero probé a poner  la misma cantidad sin variable y funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar la solución a este problema, resulta que tkinter.Entry.get() retorna un string y me había olvidado de convertirlo a integer. Por lo que estaba almacenando trillones de caracteres.

```
# si tengo una variable de tipo string
variable = "a"

# al multiplicarla por un numero obtengo ese numero de veces el string
variable * 10 
# Resultado: "aaaaaaaaaa"
```

Como cada caracter representa un byte, al tener 1 trillon de ellos ocupo 10 elevado a la 18 bytes, que es lo mismo que 1 millon de terabytes.